# How to curve a custom polygon element with a clip-path property?

Tags: css, svg, polygon, border-radius

I have a problem implementing a button with **CSS **and the concept of this button is like the picture below.

I found that the better solution can be **polygon **and **clip-path** property, but it is true that when you use polygon, you can't set radius for the corners.

**Notice**: It is important to find a solution that can utilize dynamic content and dynamic sizes of elements.

This is the concept:

[image: The Concept of my button that I have to implement]

And this is my implementation with clip-path:polygons (tailwindcss).

```html
<div
 class="w-[172px] h-12 mb-10 bg-[#F5910D] flex items-center justify-center"
 style="clip-path:polygon(10px 0,100% 0,100% calc(100% - 10px),calc(100% - 10px) 100%,0 100%,0 10px)"
 >
     <span class="text-white text-lg font-bold">All Products</span>
 </div>
```

[image]

Does anyone have any solution?

I tried to use **SVG filter** and the **stdDeviation** attribute but it wasn't working for polygons.

Comment: You polygone could be written with enough "points" to _emulate_ rounded corners. Or you use `path` instead of a polygone.

Comment: That is right. But if I want to have an element with dynamic width and height and also with dynamic content, I have to generate different numbers of points to make the same radius. Also using path maybe has this issue with dynamic size and content.

Comment: _"And this is my implementation with polygons (tailwindcss)."_ - so where in there exactly are the polygons hiding? Also, hard to tell from your image, if you only want the lower left and upper right corners rounded, or more.

Comment: Sorry the html code was wrong. I changed it.

Comment: If this is just about the bottom-left and top-right corner - then you can simply wrap this into an additional element, apply the rounded borders there, and cut off the overflow - https://jsfiddle.net/py1ce6j0/

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea. But with your solution we can't set **box-shadow** or implement **outline** button. This is your idea with extra elements for top-right and bottom-left corner - https://jsfiddle.net/8u0omzan/

Comment: Box shadow could still be implemented via a pseudo element, that gets the same clip-path and rounded borders assigned, https://jsfiddle.net/wm6k84yz/ But anything with "outlines" will hardly work with any solutions that depend on overlapping multiple elements.